# Composite components and tagfiles included in web fragment JAR load 10-20 times slower

Tags: performance, jsf, jar, taglib, myfaces

We have developed a lot of JSF 2.2 composite components and tagfiles. Using MyFaces 2.2.12 we noticed a very poor performance when they are packaged in an separate web fragment JAR.

It seems XHTML resources, when packaged in a web fragment JAR, are not optimized. The same composite components and tagfiles, when moved in the main web application, works 10/20 time faster. Any similar experience? Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you profile the application and abd pinpointed the cause of the delay?

Comment: Have you also taken the opportunity to measure it with Mojarra instead of MyFaces? If it shows the same slowdown then probably the cause should be drilled down to server's own classloader and in such case it's more helpful if you also specify which servers exactly you have tested.

Comment: Oh, also just to be sure, remember that JSF will internally not cache the loaded XHTML templates when project stage is set to Development. So if this flag is kept turned on even in production, then you might face related slowdowns.

Comment: I've tried the same scenario in a new, clean project ... and everything seems to work properly ...
So ... we're investigating in our, big, project ....